# Can I put ng-click directive in JS file instead of HTML file and how should I do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

JS code:

```
var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp', []);
nameApp.controller('NameCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ['Larry', 'Curly', 'Moe'];

    $scope.removeName = function(name) {
        var i = $scope.names.indexOf(name);
        $scope.names.splice(i, 1);
    };
});
```

HTML code:

```
<html ng-app="nameApp">
    <body ng-controller="NameCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}
                <a href="" ng-click="removeName(name)">remove</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

This is only a sample code. I want to know if I can put ng-click directive in JS file instead of HTMl file and how should I do it. Something similar to what I did in an example when I separted logic from HTML.

```
$(a).click(function(){
    $(this).removeName(name);
}
```

Comment: Not really for this trivial case. You would need a directive that would replace a core `ng-click` directive that already works fine. If your issues are more complex you have over simplified the question

Comment: Why you want to do this? Ng-click does exaclty what you want. Why to directive a directive?

Comment: You can do it, but you need some crazy coding. for  put the html element in your array, and bind it to the ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer using `ng-click`, instead of binding the event the jQuery way.

But, as you asked: you can inject your controller's `$element`, and bind the `on` event on it, see:

```js
var app = angular.module("click", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $element) {
    $element.on("click", function() {
        alert("clicked!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="click">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @leanansith You're welcome! But, did it work, after all? If so, you may consider accepting this answer as the correct one, by clicking on its checkmark.

Comment: Yup, it worked. And thanks for the instructions for using the site. There goes checkmark!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `ng-bind-html`, but my sample is looking like crazy. but it's working for me without using `ng-click` in html side

```
var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp', []);
nameApp.controller('NameCtrl', function($scope) {      

    $scope.names = ['Larry', 'Curly', 'Moe'];

        $scope.ValOfRept = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < $scope.names.length; x++) {
            var element = '<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" ng-click=\"removeName(valofrept)\">remove</a>';
            var obj = { "name": $scope.names[x], "element": element };
            $scope.ValOfRept.push(obj);
        }


        $scope.removeName = function (name) {
            var i = $scope.names.indexOf(name);
            $scope.ValOfRept.splice(i, 1);
        };

});
nameApp.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
     return function (text) {
         return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
     };
 }]);;
```

Html

```
<div ng-repeat="valofrept in ValOfRept">
        {{valofrept.name}}
      <div ng-bind-html="valofrept.element  | to_trusted"></div>
        <br />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular.element() in place of $()

Sample code:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}
       <a href="" id="clickme" ng-click="removeName(name)">remove</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and in js

```
angular.element("#clickme").bind("click", function(e){
          $scope.removeName();
       });
```

Comment: Check your post again... Should the html still have the `ng-click`? From where should the `$scope.removeName();` get the `name` parameter from?

Answer (score -2):

*"I want to know if I can put ng-click directive in JS file instead of HTMl file..."*

Precisely the place to directives is in html no js. When you use jquery your html code is like

```
<input type="button" value="x" id="test" onclick="$(this).removeName(name)"/>
```

And in your js you apply the logic that you want.

In angular is very similar. ng-click is equivalent to onclick. In your html code you have the directive ng-click and in your controller you apply the logic. I don´t understand why in angular you want to mix it.

In brief, you needn't do it, you mustn't do it.